# Unable to get transparent background in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using **shiny app** & unable to get a **transparent background** only in this plot. After looking at many **SO** post I have tried a lot of options but still **unable** to get **transparent background**.

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the covid virus shape shouldn't hide behind the plot background if plot has transparent background.

```
 output$id_india_map_cases_daily <- renderPlot({
        req(input$id_checkbox_tab1_cases_daily)

        ind_states %>%
            filter(Date == max(Date, na.rm = TRUE),
                    State.UnionTerritory != "India") %>%

            ggplot(aes(fill = .data[[input$id_checkbox_tab1_cases_daily]], label = ST_NM)) +
            geom_sf(colour = "grey", lwd = .1) +
            theme_map() +
            scale_fill_gradient2_tableau(
                palette = "Sunset-Sunrise Diverging",
                na.value = "grey50",
                guide = "colourbar") +

            theme(legend.position = "right",
                  legend.direction = "vertical",
                  plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
                  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
                  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
                  strip.background = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                  legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
                  legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

Is there any other **theme option** I can try with ?

I have another similar map down below in the App that uses same theme options but that one has transparency in the background & this can be confirmed if one changes the theme from light to dark for eg. cyborg

(UPDATE: removed app url)

(Pls close the App ASAP as this is running on free version of shinyapp which has monthly time limit).

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690259/6851825

Comment: @JonSpring, thanks for sharing this post. This did work. If you could share in the Answer then I will accept & close this post. Appreciate your help. Thanks again !!